# Define defaultstyle for custom controls inside a toolbar

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a custom Control that I want to put inside a WPF Toolbar. No Problem but I don't want to set the special Style inside the Toolbar for each Item. For native .NET Controls ( like Button, Checkbox etc. ) there is a

```
{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}
```

you can override. But it seems it's only for the native Controls. Is it possible to set a defaultstylekey for my custom Control inside the Toolbar? Or maybe I can implement a similar pattern as an extension to the Toolbar? Anyone knows a way?

As requested a short example of my Problem :

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <common:MyCustomControl Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyleInsideToolBar}" />
    <Button Content="I get styled through ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey" />
 </ToolBar>
```

Now I want my CustomControl get styled in a default way like the Button does through a special StyleKey so I don't have to set the Style each time i set it inside a ToolBar (and only inside the ToolBar!).

In Detail I am searching for a way to implement [ToolBar See Line 474](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ToolBar.cs#7acd2e55a8868635#references)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why can't you just provide a `Style` for your control? Perhaps you could show some relevant code to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: why dont you add style in your custome control itself?

Comment: Like i said ... I don't want to add style to the control everytime I add it to a toolbar. I want a different "defaultstyle" for the control if it is inside a toolbar

Comment: I guess I need to override the toolbar and a add default Style for my control there =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a style with key "DefaultStyleInsideToolBar" already defined elsewhere simply add a style to the resources of your toolbar that targets all instances of MyCustomControl that is based on your previously defined style:

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type common:MyCustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyleInsideToolBar}"/>
    </ToolBar.Resources>
    <common:MyCustomControl />
    <Button Content="I get styled through ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey" />
</ToolBar>
```